# RecyclerView with different background colors of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context

I need to make my RecyclerView item's TextView display multiple background colors. i have 5 different colors that i need to show after every 5 items.
This is my code i would know what's wrong ?
I have this ERROR:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.getColor(int)' on a null object reference at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:409)

```
public class AdapterHumeurs extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterHumeurs.MyViewholder> {

    List<Humeur> listArray;
    Context context;

    public AdapterHumeurs(List<Humeur> List){
        this.listArray = List;
    }
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewholder holder, int position) {

            Humeur data = listArray.get ( position );

            if(position % 5 == 0){
                holder.TextLabelHumeur.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color1));
            }else if(position % 5 == 1){
                holder.TextLabelHumeur.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color2));
            }else if(position % 5 == 2){
                holder.TextLabelHumeur.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color3));
            }else if(position % 5 == 3){
                holder.TextLabelHumeur.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color4));
            }else if(position % 5 == 4){
                holder.TextLabelHumeur.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color5));
            }

            holder.TextLabelHumeur.setText ( data.getLabelHumeur ( ) );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is not initialized here. You can pass ***this*** or ***ActivityName.this*** to access the context in Adapter class while creating the adapter object in your activity.

Comment: Thanks for help !!

Comment: I want that when i clicked an item in my recyclerView the page which contain the details (second activity) will have the same background color of the clicked item.
How can i do this in my setOnClickListener method ? thanks

Comment: Yes use setonclicklistner on your view using holder. And while using intent flag as below,
Intent intent=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: :I don't understand how can i use " intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); " to pass the background color of the clicked item to the next activity who should have the same background color ?